# Histogram of all variables, different y-axis scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot an histogram of all my variables using `ggplot`.
I have a dataset of 10 variables and i performed clustering on individuals.
Now I want to plot each variable distribution by cluster group.

I'm aware that I can do

```
melt.cluster.data<-melt(cluster.data,id="CLUSTER")

ggplot(melt.cluster.data,aes(value))+
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(variable~CLUSTER)
```

The problem is that the variable distribution is very different in each clusters and also the distribution of individuals is very different in each clusters.

As a results, some graphs are impossible to visualize, like in the example

[image]

How can i have histograms with y-axis scale tailored to each individuals distribution inside the clusters?
Thanks

Comment: Try with `facet_wrap(variable~CLUSTER, scales="free_y")`. By default, the panels have the same axes but you can relax that with the `scales` argument.

Comment: And since you are plotting histograms, you can also consider plotting the densities, not the raw counts, with the y scale fixed. That could also make the panels more comparable: `geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.